# Duplicate Form Fields if Radio is Selected

Tags: jquery, forms, duplicates, field

Is it possible to use jQuery to 'duplicate' a few form fields (text, radio, select)? The fields would need to be duplicated but have individual IDs from the originals for validation sake.

If the radio field "Child Count" choice "2 or more" is selected, duplicate the previous fields.

I'm open to suggestions. I'm hoping it's possible to just add the list item IDs via jQuery rather than having to basically recreate the form via jQuery. I hope I've explained this well enough but let me know if it's at all confusing.

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="gform_ajax_frame_2" id="gform_2" action="/about-us/publications-and-forms/youth-basketball-registration-form/#gf_2">
                        <div class="gform_body"><ul id="gform_fields_2" class="gform_fields top_label form_sublabel_above description_above"><li id="field_2_3" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_above field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_2_3_3">Player's Name<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_complex ginput_container no_prefix has_first_name has_middle_name has_last_name no_suffix" id="input_2_3">
                            
                            <span id="input_2_3_3_container" class="name_first">
                                                    <label for="input_2_3_3">First</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="input_3.3" id="input_2_3_3" value="" aria-label="First name" tabindex="50" placeholder="First" style="cursor: auto; background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==); background-attachment: scroll; background-position: 100% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                                                </span>
                            <span id="input_2_3_4_container" class="name_middle">
                                                    <label for="input_2_3_4">Middle</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="input_3.4" id="input_2_3_4" value="" aria-label="Middle name" tabindex="51" placeholder="Middle">
                                                </span>
                            <span id="input_2_3_6_container" class="name_last">
                                                            <label for="input_2_3_6">Last</label>
                                                            <input type="text" name="input_3.6" id="input_2_3_6" value="" aria-label="Last name" tabindex="52" placeholder="Last">
                                                        </span>
                            
                        </div></li><li id="field_2_4" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_above field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_2_4">Grade<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_container"><input name="input_4" id="input_2_4" type="number" step="any" value="" class="small" tabindex="54" placeholder="Grade"></div></li><li id="field_2_5" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_above field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_2_5">Birthday<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_container">
                            <input name="input_5" id="input_2_5" type="text" value="" class="datepicker medium mdy datepicker_no_icon hasDatepicker" tabindex="55" placeholder="Birthday">
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="gforms_calendar_icon_input_2_5" class="gform_hidden" value="http://bgcgeneva.org/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/images/calendar.png"></li><li id="field_2_9" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_above field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label">Sex<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_container"><ul class="gfield_radio" id="input_2_9"><li class="gchoice_2_9_0"><input name="input_9" type="radio" value="M" id="choice_2_9_0" tabindex="56"><label for="choice_2_9_0" id="label_2_9_0">M</label></li><li class="gchoice_2_9_1"><input name="input_9" type="radio" value="F" id="choice_2_9_1" tabindex="57"><label for="choice_2_9_1" id="label_2_9_1">F</label></li></ul></div></li><li id="field_2_8" class="gfield field_sublabel_above field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_2_8">Ethnicity</label><div class="ginput_container"><input name="input_8" id="input_2_8" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="58" placeholder="Ethnicity"></div></li><li id="field_2_6" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_above field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_2_6">Phone<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_container"><input name="input_6" id="input_2_6" type="tel" value="" class="medium" tabindex="59" placeholder="Phone"></div></li><li id="field_2_7" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_above field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_2_7_1">Address<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>    
                    <div class="ginput_complex ginput_container has_street has_street2 has_city has_state has_zip" id="input_2_7">
                         <span class="ginput_full address_line_1" id="input_2_7_1_container">
                                        <label for="input_2_7_1" id="input_2_7_1_label">Street Address</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="input_7.1" id="input_2_7_1" value="" tabindex="60" placeholder="Address">
                                    </span><span class="ginput_full address_line_2" id="input_2_7_2_container">
                                        <label for="input_2_7_2" id="input_2_7_2_label">Address Line 2</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="input_7.2" id="input_2_7_2" value="" tabindex="61" placeholder="Address Line 2">
                                    </span><span class="ginput_left address_city" id="input_2_7_3_container">
                                    <label for="input_2_7_3" id="input_2_7_3_label">City</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="input_7.3" id="input_2_7_3" value="" tabindex="62" placeholder="City">
                                 </span><span class="ginput_right address_state" id="input_2_7_4_container">
                                        <label for="input_2_7_4" id="input_2_7_4_label">State</label>
                                        <select name="input_7.4" id="input_2_7_4" tabindex="63"><option value="">State</option><option value="Alabama">Alabama</option><option value="Alaska">Alaska</option><option value="Arizona">Arizona</option><option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option><option value="California">California</option><option value="Colorado">Colorado</option><option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option><option value="Delaware">Delaware</option><option value="District of Columbia">District of Columbia</option><option value="Florida">Florida</option><option value="Georgia">Georgia</option><option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option><option value="Idaho">Idaho</option><option value="Illinois">Illinois</option><option value="Indiana">Indiana</option><option value="Iowa">Iowa</option><option value="Kansas">Kansas</option><option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option><option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option><option value="Maine">Maine</option><option value="Maryland">Maryland</option><option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option><option value="Michigan">Michigan</option><option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option><option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option><option value="Missouri">Missouri</option><option value="Montana">Montana</option><option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option><option value="Nevada">Nevada</option><option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option><option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option><option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option><option value="New York" selected="selected">New York</option><option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option><option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option><option value="Ohio">Ohio</option><option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option><option value="Oregon">Oregon</option><option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option><option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option><option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option><option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option><option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option><option value="Texas">Texas</option><option value="Utah">Utah</option><option value="Vermont">Vermont</option><option value="Virginia">Virginia</option><option value="Washington">Washington</option><option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option><option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option><option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option><option value="Armed Forces Americas">Armed Forces Americas</option><option value="Armed Forces Europe">Armed Forces Europe</option><option value="Armed Forces Pacific">Armed Forces Pacific</option></select>
                                      </span><span class="ginput_left address_zip" id="input_2_7_5_container">
                                    <label for="input_2_7_5" id="input_2_7_5_label">ZIP Code</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="input_7.5" id="input_2_7_5" value="" tabindex="65" placeholder="Zip">
                                </span><input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="input_7.6" id="input_2_7_6" value="United States">
                    <div class="gf_clear gf_clear_complex"></div>
                </div></li><li id="field_2_10" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_above field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_2_10_3">Parent/Guardian Name<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_complex ginput_container no_prefix has_first_name no_middle_name has_last_name no_suffix" id="input_2_10">
                            
                            <span id="input_2_10_3_container" class="name_first">
                                                    <label for="input_2_10_3">First</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="input_10.3" id="input_2_10_3" value="" aria-label="First name" tabindex="67" placeholder="Parent/Guardian First Name">
                                                </span>
                            
                            <span id="input_2_10_6_container" class="name_last">
                                                            <label for="input_2_10_6">Last</label>
                                                            <input type="text" name="input_10.6" id="input_2_10_6" value="" aria-label="Last name" tabindex="69" placeholder="Parent/Guardian Last Name">
                                                        </span>
                            
                        </div></li><li id="field_2_11" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_above field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_2_11">Parent/Guardian Email<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_container">
                            <input name="input_11" id="input_2_11" type="email" value="" class="medium" tabindex="71" placeholder="Parent/Guardian Email">
                        </div></li><li id="field_2_12" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_above field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_2_12_3">Emergency contact other than parent/guardian<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_complex ginput_container no_prefix has_first_name no_middle_name has_last_name no_suffix" id="input_2_12">
                            
                            <span id="input_2_12_3_container" class="name_first">
                                                    <label for="input_2_12_3">First</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="input_12.3" id="input_2_12_3" value="" aria-label="First name" tabindex="73" placeholder="First">
                                                </span>
                            
                            <span id="input_2_12_6_container" class="name_last">
                                                            <label for="input_2_12_6">Last</label>
                                                            <input type="text" name="input_12.6" id="input_2_12_6" value="" aria-label="Last name" tabindex="75" placeholder="Last">
                                                        </span>
                            
                        </div></li><li id="field_2_13" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_above field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_2_13">Emergency contact phone number other than parent/guardian<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_container"><input name="input_13" id="input_2_13" type="tel" value="" class="medium" tabindex="77"></div></li><li id="field_2_26" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_above field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label">Player's Shirt Size<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_container"><ul class="gfield_radio" id="input_2_26"><li class="gchoice_2_26_0"><input name="input_26" type="radio" value="Child Sm" id="choice_2_26_0" tabindex="78"><label for="choice_2_26_0" id="label_2_26_0">Child Sm</label></li><li class="gchoice_2_26_1"><input name="input_26" type="radio" value="Child Med" id="choice_2_26_1" tabindex="79"><label for="choice_2_26_1" id="label_2_26_1">Child Med</label></li><li class="gchoice_2_26_2"><input name="input_26" type="radio" value="Child Lg" id="choice_2_26_2" tabindex="80"><label for="choice_2_26_2" id="label_2_26_2">Child Lg</label></li><li class="gchoice_2_26_3"><input name="input_26" type="radio" value="Adult Sm" id="choice_2_26_3" tabindex="81"><label for="choice_2_26_3" id="label_2_26_3">Adult Sm</label></li><li class="gchoice_2_26_4"><input name="input_26" type="radio" value="Adult Med" id="choice_2_26_4" tabindex="82"><label for="choice_2_26_4" id="label_2_26_4">Adult Med</label></li><li class="gchoice_2_26_5"><input name="input_26" type="radio" value="Adult Lg" id="choice_2_26_5" tabindex="83"><label for="choice_2_26_5" id="label_2_26_5">Adult Lg</label></li><li class="gchoice_2_26_6"><input name="input_26" type="radio" value="Adult XL" id="choice_2_26_6" tabindex="84"><label for="choice_2_26_6" id="label_2_26_6">Adult XL</label></li></ul></div></li><li id="field_2_15" class="gfield gfield_price gfield_price_2_15 gfield_product_2_15 gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_above field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label">Child Count<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_container"><ul class="gfield_radio" id="input_2_15"><li class="gchoice_2_15_0"><input name="input_15" type="radio" value="One Child|70" id="choice_2_15_0" tabindex="85" onclick="gf_apply_rules(2,[32,28,29,30,31]);"><label for="choice_2_15_0" id="label_2_15_0">One Child</label></li><li class="gchoice_2_15_1"><input name="input_15" type="radio" value="2 or more|90" id="choice_2_15_1" tabindex="86" onclick="gf_apply_rules(2,[32,28,29,30,31]);"><label for="choice_2_15_1" id="label_2_15_1">2 or more</label></li></ul></div></li><li id="field_2_33" class="gfield gform_validation_container field_sublabel_above field_description_above"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_2_33">Comments</label><div class="gfield_description">This field is for validation purposes and should be left unchanged.</div><div class="ginput_container"><input name="input_33" id="input_2_33" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off"></div></li>
                            </ul></div>
        <div class="gform_footer top_label"> <input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_2" class="gform_button button" value="Submit" tabindex="111" onclick="if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_2&quot;]){return false;}  if( !jQuery(&quot;#gform_2&quot;)[0].checkValidity || jQuery(&quot;#gform_2&quot;)[0].checkValidity()){window[&quot;gf_submitting_2&quot;]=true;}  "> <input type="hidden" name="gform_ajax" value="form_id=2&amp;title=&amp;description=&amp;tabindex=49">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="is_submit_2" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_submit" value="2">
            
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_unique_id" value="">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="state_2" value="WyJ7XCIxNVwiOltcImJhMDk1MTA1MTBmY2Q4NWIxMmQxMGMzODhlMmUyZjgyXCIsXCI0YjQ2NDE1YWMyMTAwNzFjYWU0NDE3M2I1MzY0ZWU1ZVwiXX0iLCJmMTZmNWI3ZGFiNjJjZDJkMmRjMTljMTFjMGJkM2Y1YSJd">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_target_page_number_2" id="gform_target_page_number_2" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_source_page_number_2" id="gform_source_page_number_2" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="gform_field_values" value="">
            
        </div>
                        </form>
```